# Find and replace commas between quotation marks

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string

```
line='Aaron JamesNorman662018,1956,Aaron James,Norman,Aaron,Aaron James,Pangea Ventures,Zone 20,Field,Parkwest,"Director,Human Resourse",Leasing Agent 2 (L2),DeLana Watson,2018-06-06,2019-09-27 00:00:00,Terminated'
```

I need to remove the comma between the double quote, in this case  is the comma between 'Director' and 'Human Resource'.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the line you are working with is CSV.  You should not try to modify structured text directly.  Rather than trying to manipulate `line` as a string, use a CSV module to process the fields, modify the data, and then regenerate the CSV line.  Here's a link to the docs for the standard CSV package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I don't know python, but can't you use something like `replace()`? like: 
`line.replace("Director,Human Resourse", "Director Human Resourse");`

Answer (score 0):

I think this re works for my case

line=re.sub(r'(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),', '', line)